# Dead keys aren't working in wine

Tags: wine, keyboard-layout, playonlinux, locale, dead-keys

I'm trying to use MS-Office 2010 (I know... it's pretty old) with Wine and everything but my dead keys are not working perfectly.

With any other application in Ubuntu 16.04 they works well...

To clarify and give some examples:

1. [This is my physical keyboard layout](https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-blhknq8/product_images/images/Toshiba_Portege_Z930_laptop_key.jpg) "Toshiba Portegé-z835 keyboard"
2. It has been logically configured as pt_BR, USA International with dead keys. This configuration allows it to work perfectly in any application, e.g: Chrome, gedit, atom, terminal, etc.
3. When running MS-Office apps with PlayOnLinux and Wine, I try to use some of the following keys:
   <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd> or <kbd>`</kbd>; but nothing happens. It seems that they are ignored.

My current locale is:

```
LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=pt_BR:pt:en
LC_CTYPE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

How can I get these keys working in MS Office?

Comment: What do you mean by a dead key?

Comment: @Ravexina https://askubuntu.com/tags/dead-keys/info

Comment: @Terrance thanks, I didn't pay attention to the tag ;)

Comment: @Ravexina No problem.  =)

Comment: Maybe WineHQ might help?  https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=17307

Comment: i've had mixed results inputting unicode into wine applications.  the `Ctrl+Shift+U xxxx` method usually fails.  with some applications, copy/paste via the X clipboard is possible.  other applications work with nondeadkey layouts using AltGr or Compose sequences, and i'd suspect those should work with deadkeys as well (though i never tested that).  you may need to give us specifics about what application you're trying to input to.